# PostgreSQL column does not exist when sub select

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called user, and I need to get another users in an expecific distance range and the distance between them. My query is this:

```
select ( 6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) )
              *    cos( radians(-22.9035) )
              * cos( radians(-43.2096) - radians(users.longitude) )
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) )
              * sin( radians(-22.9035) ) 
              ) 
    ) as distance, users from users where users.id != 41 and distance > 50
```

I need to recover the user list and the distance, but the "as distance" is not working:

```
ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist.
```

I tried with:

```
with distance as (
select ( 6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) )
              * cos( radians(-22.9035) )
              * cos( radians(-43.2096) - radians(users.longitude) )
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) )
              * sin( radians(-22.9035) ) 
              ) 
    ) from users
)
select * from users where users.id != 41 and distance > 50
```

However, the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you cannot use column aliases in a where clause. That's why your first query does not work.

Your second query using a CTE can be made to work, but `distance` is a virtual table, not a column. Join with it.

```
with users_distance as (
  select
    id,
    ( 6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) )
              * cos( radians(-22.9035) )
              * cos( radians(-43.2096) - radians(users.longitude) )
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) )
              * sin( radians(-22.9035) ) 
              ) 
    ) as distance
  from users
)
select *
from users
join users_distance ud on users.id = ud.id
where users.id != 41 and ud.distance > 50
```

If you do this a lot, consider adding a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) to the table so you don't have to recalculated it all the time.

```
alter table users add column distance numeric
  generated always as (
    6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) )
              * cos( radians(-22.9035) )
              * cos( radians(-43.2096) - radians(users.longitude) )
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) )
              * sin( radians(-22.9035) ) 
              )
  ) stored
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d15eb01b85f83cf442957082a7b37a6e)

Finally, rather than doing these calculations yourself, consider using the very powerful [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) extension.